# How to centralize image in header of Navigation View?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I need to centralize image in header of Navigaion view. First of all i tried to set `layout_gravity` and `gravity` to `center_vertical` and `layout_centerVertical="true"`. This didn't help. Next step was set `margins` and `padding`. This didn't help too. And now i don't know to do to centralize it. Here's my code

**nav_header**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user"
            android:background="@drawable/user"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Charla"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent_white"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLastName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reeves"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent_white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**navigation view**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_list"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/menu_text_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/menu_text_color"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_view_background"

        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Here's how it looks in preview(how i need it to be displayed):

[image]

Here's how it actually looks when i run app :

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is, make the screenshot a little bigger to include the status bar.

Comment: @Mihai i edit my question. My image and text must be on vertical_center, and not like what i'm getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that the navigation drawer draws under the status bar (which is 24 dip high). Read more about it [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec).

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: you can ether add top margin to your layout (which is kind of a hack). Or make your app not use the space under the status bar(add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the navigation layout).

Comment: adding margin wont help :(

Comment: and another tip, you should use constraint layout is a lot more efficient then a linear layout inside a relative layout

Comment: you have to add the margin to the image and the linear layout not the parent

Comment: Margin works, i tested this on another devise, my fail)

Comment: glad to hear it but is kinda of a hack, you can read that article to see how you can make the system add that padding for you.